# How to import Tensorflow source codes correctly with Clion or Netbeans

Tags: c++, vim, netbeans, tensorflow, clion

I intend to read the core module of Tensorflow(TF) source codes

My problem is I do not have experience reading C/C++ source codes like TF in IDE. Could anyone give me some instructions regarding how to read TF source codes (core module) efficiently in a IDE. I have **Clion and Netbeans** on my Macbook but I don't know how to import TF correctly(also which part to import?;how to build it?) such that when I want to know the declaration of one C++ class I can jump to its signature/declaration directly.

I will appreciate any advice/recommended tools for reading TF source codes efficiently. BTW, I am assuming reading TF codes with a IDE is efficient. If it is not true, I can stop using them and turn to tools like VIM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original Tensorflow repository([GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow)) does not contain project information file for any specific IDE, which means you cannot just import the whole project unless you are using something which can import files based on the project folder ([Atom](https://atom.io/), [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) etc.) I would suggest using one of those if your aim is just to read an navigate inside the code base.

Unfortunately you wont be able to build the code with any of those editors. Tensorflow uses [Bazel](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-overview.html) as its build tool which has support at the moment for Eclipse and Xcode. Honestly, I'm not sure if you can import the the code base in one of this IDEs either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem doing this:

1. Create CMakeLists.txt file inside TF repo. ls -la output should look like this:

```
tensorflow
third-party
tools
CMakeLists.txt
some
other
files
```

2. CMakeLists.txt should look like this:

NOTE!!! This is not a complete file because a complete file should be 800+ lines long. This is just an example for you to get the idea. You can get the complete file here:

https://github.com/oleg-ostanin/tf_related_staff/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

but it will probably become outdated next week so don't even bother.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(tensorflow)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# git clone https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
include_directories(/home/oostanin/tf_related_repos/abseil-cpp)

# git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
include_directories(/home/oostanin/tf_related_repos/protobuf/src/)

include_directories(/home/oostanin/tensorflow)

# you can get this directory only by building TF from sources using Bazel
include_directories(/home/oostanin/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles)

file(GLOB tensorflow_contrib_tensorrt_shape_fn "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/shape_fn/*.cc")
file(GLOB tensorflow_compiler_xla_service_llvm_ir "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/llvm_ir/*.cc")
file(GLOB tensorflow_lite_delegates_gpu_gl "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/gl/*.cc")
# here should be much more lines

add_library(
        tensorflow

        SHARED

        ${tensorflow_contrib_tensorrt_shape_fn}
        ${tensorflow_compiler_xla_service_llvm_ir}
        ${tensorflow_lite_delegates_gpu_gl}
        # here should be much more lines too
                )

target_link_libraries(
        tensorflow
        )
```

Some explanations:

TF source files depend on many other projects so you will need to clone and place those projects somewhere near and tell your Cmake where to find them. This is what those 2 lines do:

```
# git clone https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
include_directories(/home/oostanin/tf_related_repos/abseil-cpp)

# git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
include_directories(/home/oostanin/tf_related_repos/protobuf/src/)
```

There is probably more than 2 repos, but that will get you started.

TF source files depend on compiled protobuf headers and the easiest way for me to compile them turned out to build TF from sources using Bazel. This is another painful story but I did it and I'm sure you can do it too. Than you should tell your Cmake where to find those compiled protobuf headers. This is what that line do:

```
include_directories(/home/oostanin/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles)
```

If you can't build TF using Bazel, just skip that part, you will see more red errors caused by unsatisfied includes, but you will be able to read and navigate most of the code.

You should tell Cmake where to find TF source files and the easiest way for me was to generate 300+ lines long list of all directories containing .cc files like this:

```
file(GLOB tensorflow_contrib_tensorrt_shape_fn "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/shape_fn/*.cc")
file(GLOB tensorflow_compiler_xla_service_llvm_ir "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/llvm_ir/*.cc")
file(GLOB tensorflow_lite_delegates_gpu_gl "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/gl/*.cc")
# here should be much more lines
```

and then generate another 300+ lines long list to include them as sources like this:

```
add_library(
        tensorflow

        SHARED

        ${tensorflow_contrib_tensorrt_shape_fn}
        ${tensorflow_compiler_xla_service_llvm_ir}
        ${tensorflow_lite_delegates_gpu_gl}
        # here should be much more lines too
                )
```

There is no way you can build TF using that CMakeLists.txt, don't even think about it. But it will allow you to import TF source code into CLion and read and navigate and edit much easier than using VIM.